# What is the Android coroutine equivalent to Executor service

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have an `ExecutorService` code snippet, and I am trying to convert it to coroutines in order to test performance. However no matter how I structure the coroutine code, `ExecutorService` is much faster. I thought that coroutines are supposed to improve performance

functionality:

- run in background thread
- execute 200000 actions (counter++)
- post time that passed to UI thread
- the code runs in a ViewModel updating a time text view
- executor service code take ~150 milliseconds on an emulator
- any coroutines code I wrote takes a lot longer

what would be the coroutine equivalent to the following code :

```
fun runCodeExecutorService() {
        spinner.value = true
        val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2)
        val result = AtomicInteger()

        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val handler: Handler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            override fun handleMessage(inputMessage: Message) {
                time.value = toTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
                spinner.value = false
                Log.d("tag", "counter Executor = " + result.get())
            }
        }
        thread(start = true) {
            for (i in 1..NUMBER_OF_THREADS) {
                executorService.execute {
                    result.getAndIncrement()
                }
            }
            executorService.shutdown();
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            val msg: Message = handler.obtainMessage()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("MSG_KEY", result.get())
            msg.data = bundle

            handler.sendMessage(msg)
        }
    }
```

where NUMBER_OF_CORES is `val NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`
NUMBER_OF_THREADS is 200000

Answer (score 0):

A rough equivalent is dispatchers.

```kotlin
suspend fun aLotOfCoroutines() {
    spinner.value = true
    val result = AtomicInteger()

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    coroutineScope {
        repeat(NUMBER_OF_THREADS) {
            launch(Dispatchers.Default) { // 1
                result.getAndIncrement()
            }
        }
    } // 2

    // 3
    time.value = toTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
    spinner.value = false
    Log.d("tag", "counter Dispatchers.Default = " + result.get())
}
```

1. Instead of creating and stopping a new executor, we can use [`Dispatchers.Default`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html) for non-blocking tasks.
2. With structured concurrency, [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) does not return until all of its child coroutines are finished. That's why we do not need to explicitly wait for the completion.
3. Because this method is called in `Dispatchers.Main`, these line will be also be run in the main thread.

---

If you really want to use a custom thread pool, you can use the [`asCoroutineDispatcher`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/java.util.concurrent.-executor-service/as-coroutine-dispatcher.html) extension method on the executor.

---

I did a bit more investigations after knowing that OP is interested in the performance numbers.

In this "test":

1. The task is cheap. So any overhead per task is very pronounced.
2. This task is acting on a resource so heavily contended that it's faster **not** to parallelize. Running it single-threaded took 1ms.

I think it's fair to say that this is not like any real workload.

Anyway, the following worker pool achieves a similar time with the thread pool.

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
    val channel = produce(capacity = 64) {
        repeat(JOB_COUNT) { send(Unit) }
    }

    // The fewer workers we launch, the faster it runs
    repeat(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2) {
        launch {
            for (task in channel) {
                result.getAndIncrement()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@George actually your code is blocking, the actual code might look something like this:

```
fun runCodeCoroutines() = viewModelScope.launch {
        spinner.value = true
        val result = AtomicInteger()

        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            result.aLotOfCoroutines()
        }

        // 3
        time.value = toTime(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
        spinner.value = false
        Log.d("tag", "counter Dispatchers.Default = " + result.get())

    }
```

```
suspend fun AtomicInteger.aLotOfCoroutines() {

        coroutineScope {
            repeat(NUMBER_OF_THREADS) {
                launch(Dispatchers.Default) { // 1
                    getAndIncrement()
                }
            }
        } // 2

    }
```

where aLotOfCoroutines, is your code
this is approximately the result I got.

benchmark:
coroutines code ~ 1.2 seconds
executor code ~ 150 milliseconds

there is another version of the code where I break the number of threads into 200*1000

```
suspend fun massiveRun(action: suspend () -> Unit) {
        coroutineScope { // scope for coroutines
            repeat(NUMBER_OF_TASKS) {
                launch {
                    repeat(NUMBER_OF_ACTIONS) { action() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

which takes ~ 35 - 40 milliseconds
however, the same breakdown in Executor service takes ~ 25 - 35 milliseconds

which is closer but still overall better

**my conclusion is that when looking at performance Executor Service is still more performant than Coroutines**

and coroutines are only better in syntax and when precise performance is not important (i.e network calls etc.)

Comment: I took your question as "how to write task spawning in idiomatic Kotlin coroutines" (equivalent semantically). And it turns out you are writing a benchmark. A coroutine is of course heavier than a `Runnable`. It can pause and resume without blocking a thread; it manages cancellation and timeout. This is quite an apples-to-oranges comparison.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I thought I was clear that time is of the essence in my question. Coroutines are documented as lightweight threads, and this official link: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines-adv suggest that coroutines improve performance (i.e. improves the current situation, where most apps will have an executor mechanism), whereas I understand from the benchmark that it doesn't necessarily improve it, it's just cleaner and easier to use

 is there a way, performance-wise, that coroutines are better than Executors?

Comment: They are lighter-weight than threads. If your network call blocks a thread, you should expect the performance to increase by switching to callbacks. Since callbacks are difficult to manage, coroutine is an abstraction to handle them. I think this is where performance claim comes from.

Comment: An `Executor` can be used as a coroutine dispatcher. This tells you that coroutine is a higher level of abstraction over callbacks. You can consider the code between a coroutine's resumption and suspension to be a `Runnable` for the executor to run.